# How to access /storage/emulated/0/ from PC?

Tags: internal-storage, file-system, file-transfer, k9-mail

I want to export the settings of the [K9 mail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fsck.k9) app. This app exports a settings file to /storage/emulated/0/com.fsck.k9/settings-4.k9s. But if I connect my Nexus 4 to my PC I cannot see such a file or the directories.

Comment: `/storage/emulated/0` is the "internal SDCard", which should be what's displayed when connecting the device to your computer. I don't own a Nexus, but on most devices that place is available also as either `/sdcard` or `/mnt/sdcard`. Do you have any of these two places, and maybe can find your export there?

Comment: I can only see folders of other apps, if I connect the phone to the PC.

Answer (score 15):

The solution was to reboot the phone. The `com.fsck.k9` directory is now visible on the top level of the phones file system.

Comment: Did the trick for me too. Before a reboot, I could not access the wav files recorded by [Field Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.pfitzinger.rec).

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar issue, I could find the location, but no videos would populate.  I have to change the usb connection mode from Camera to Media ( I know, duh ).